# single byte array to 2d byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a byte array of

```
byte[] d = new byte[64];
```

now i want to convert it to a 2d byte array like ..

```
byte[,] data = new byte[8,8];
```

can any one help me on this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be one of method.

```
byte[] d = new byte[64];
byte[,] data = new byte[8,8];

int row = 0;
int column = 0;

for(i=0; i < d.Length; i++)
{
   row = i%8;
   column = i/8;
   data [row, column] = d[i];    
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks but need some editing if u permit me i will do it in the ans .. it worked for me thanks

Comment: You can or You can tell me so that I would make that.

Comment: make it `d.Length` and `data[column,row]` thats it

Comment: Thanks @Drone, So nice of you. Made those changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Buffer.BlockCopy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx):

```
byte[] d = new byte[64];
byte[,] data = new byte[8,8];

Buffer.BlockCopy(d, 0, data, 0, 64);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
byte[] d = new byte[64];

for (byte i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
    d[i] = i;

byte[,] data = new byte[8, 8];

Enumerable.Range(0, 8).ToList().
    ForEach(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 8).ToList().
        ForEach(j => data[i, j] = d[i * 8 + j]));
```